# How to convert yearly dataframe to monthly dataframe

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame as follows:

```
 A1     A2     A3           
  1      2      3     
  1      2      3
```

I would like to convert the dataframe above into something like this:

```
 M1    M1    M1  ..... M1     M2    M2  ...... M3     M3     M3  ...... M3
  1     1     1  .....  1      2     2  ......  2      3      3  ......  3
  1     1     1  .....  1      2     2  ......  2      3      3  ......  3
```

where M1, M2 and M3 are repeated 12 times (for each month)

I have tried the `duplicate` function. It worked if I only attempted to duplicate one column. However, everything went haywire if I tried more than 2 columns.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert annual data to monthly data using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902632/how-to-convert-annual-data-to-monthly-data-using-r)

Comment: Like this? `xy <- data.frame(A1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 = 3); xy[, rep(1:3, each = 12)]`.