# Pandas: Convert annual data to decade data

Tags: python, pandas

**Background**

I want to determine the global cumulative value of a variable for different decades starting from 1990 to 2014 i.e. 1990, 2000, 2010 (3 decades separately). I have annual data for different countries. However, data availability is not uniform.

[image: Sample of data shown in the table]

**Existing questions**

Uses R: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902632/how-to-convert-annual-data-to-monthly-data-using-r)

Following questions look at date formatting issues: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191697/resample-daily-data-to-monthly-with-pandas-date-formatting), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997339/convert-daily-data-in-pandas-dataframe-to-monthly-data)

Answers to these questions do not address the current question.

**Current question**

How to obtain a global sum for the period of different decades using features/tools of Pandas?

**Expected outcome**

> 1990-2000 x1
>
> 2000-2010 x2
>
> 2010-2015 x3

**Method used so far**

```
data_binned = data_pivoted.copy()
decade = []

# obtaining decade values for each country

for i in range(1960, 2017):

    if i in list(data_binned):

        # adding the columns into the decade list
        decade.append(i)

    if i % 10 == 0:

        # adding large header so that newly created columns are set at the end of the dataframe
        data_binned[i *10] = data_binned.apply(lambda x: sum(x[j] for j in decade), axis=1)
        decade = []

for x in list(data_binned):
    if x < 3000:
        # removing non-decade columns
        del data_binned[x]

# renaming the decade columns
new_names = [int(x/10) for x in list(data_binned)]
data_binned.columns = new_names

# computing global values
global_values = data_binned.sum(axis=0)
```

This is a non-optimal method because of less experience in using Pandas. Kindly suggest a better method which uses features of Pandas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) called `df` looking like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         1990: [1, 12, 45, 67, 78],
...         1999: [1, 12, 45, 67, 78],
...         2000: [34, 6, 67, 21, 65],
...         2009: [34, 6, 67, 21, 65],
...         2010: [3, 6, 6, 2, 6555],
...         2015: [3, 6, 6, 2, 6555],
...     }, index=['country_1', 'country_2', 'country_3', 'country_4', 'country_5']
... )
>>> print(df)
           1990  1999  2000  2009  2010  2015
country_1     1     1    34    34     3     3
country_2    12    12     6     6     6     6
country_3    45    45    67    67     6     6
country_4    67    67    21    21     2     2
country_5    78    78    65    65  6555  6555
```

I could make another [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) called `df_decades` with decades statistics like this:

```
>>> df_decades = pd.DataFrame()
>>> 
>>> for decade in set([(col // 10) * 10 for col in df.columns]):
...     cols_in_decade = [col for col in df.columns if (col // 10) * 10 == decade]
...     df_decades[f'{decade}-{decade + 9}'] = df[cols_in_decade].sum(axis=1)
>>>
>>> df_decades = df_decades[sorted(df_decades.columns)]
>>> print(df_decades)
           1990-1999  2000-2009  2010-2019
country_1          2         68          6
country_2         24         12         12
country_3         90        134         12
country_4        134         42          4
country_5        156        130      13110
```

The idea behind this is to iterate over all possible decades provided by column names in `df`, filtering those columns, which are part of the decade and aggregating them.

Finally, I could merge these data frames together, so my data frame `df` could be enriched by decades statistics from the second data frame `df_decades`.

```
>>> df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_decades, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
>>> print(df)
           1990  1999  2000  2009  2010  2015  1990-1999  2000-2009  2010-2019
country_1     1     1    34    34     3     3          2         68          6
country_2    12    12     6     6     6     6         24         12         12
country_3    45    45    67    67     6     6         90        134         12
country_4    67    67    21    21     2     2        134         42          4
country_5    78    78    65    65  6555  6555        156        130      13110
```